# Cannot add PPA repository

Tags: command-line, repository

Whenever I try run the following command it gives me an error:

```
dmacs@dmacs-HP40:~$ sudo apt-get-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
sudo: apt-get-repository: command not found
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: It's `add-apt-repository` not
`apt-get-repository`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no such command as `apt-get-repository`.

The correct command is `apt-add-repository`:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:nae-team/ppa
```

Comment: when i do that I always get the following error,                                             "Cannot add PPA: 'ppa:nae-team/ppa'.
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct" How to resolve that !! Because of this I cannot proceed further

Comment: @Imperial can't reproduce..what command did you run exactly?

Comment: ok, editing the question

Comment: @Imperial no, you just can not do it like that..that produces a whole different question than the original one and making my answer misdirected..it would be best to ask it as a new question leaving this one as it is..